# Getting wrong answer for Arranging Tasks #1704 in urionlinejudge

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Your boss has told you that you have only one computer to complete some tasks. Each of them earns the company an amount v of money and must be finished up to t hours from now. After that, it cannot be performed anymore and has no more value. The computer completes exactly one task per hour.

You want to impress your boss so he might give you a promotion. To do that, you intend to use your programming skills to select which tasks execute in such a way that the amount of money lost is minimized.

Input

The input is composed of several test cases and ends with end of file. Each one describes a list of tasks and starts with two integers N (1 ≤N) and H (H ≤ 1000), which are, respectively, the number of tasks and the number of hours that the computer is available. Then follow N lines, each one with two integer v (1 ≤ v ≤ 1000) and t (1 ≤ t ≤ H) described above.

Output

For each test case output a line with an integer representing the minimum lost money.

```
Sample Input    Sample Output
3 3             0   
5 1             3
10 2
20 3
4 2
1 2 
2 1 
4 1 
2 2
```

I am solving with many complex test cases like given below, getting expected results but still getting 100% wrong answer on submission. My approach is sorting the array in descending order according to the money-value and then below logic.What is wrong in my algorithm?

```
Input       Output
5 3         30
10 1        30 
20 2        1
50 2        0
40 3         
30 3
4 5    test case 1
10 1
20 1
50 2
40 2 
6 5    test case 2
10 1
12 4 
15 5
20 5
1 5
30 5
3 1000
1000 1000
2 1
3 3
```

In the below code - test case 1(4 5) and test case 2(6 5) works fine as tlarge is less for test case 1 and most tasks in test case 2 can be done in 5 hrs so the equal flag has not been set to true.

```
while(hours < H && z < N)
            {
                if(equal[Arr[z].getT()]!=true && hours<tlarge) {
                        loss -= Arr[z].getV();
                        equal[Arr[z].getT()]=true;
                        hours++;
                    }
                else
                {
                    int time=Arr[z].getT()-1;
                    while(time>0)
                    {
                        if(equal[time]==false)
                        {
                            loss -= Arr[z].getV();
                            hours++;
                            if(Arr[z].getT()<=hours)
                            {
                                int time1 = Arr[z].getT()-1;
                                while(time1>0)
                                {
                                    equal[time1]=true;
                                    time1--;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        time--;
                    }
                }
                z++;
            }
```

Here is my code -

```cs
class Entry
{
    private int v;
    private int t;

    Entry(int v, int t) {
          this.v = v;
          this.t = t;
    }

    public int getV() {
        return v;
    }

    public int getT() {
        return t;
    }  
}

public class Main {
    public final static Entry[] Arr = new Entry[1003];
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        while(true){
                String T = in.readLine();
                if(T==null) {
                    break;
                }
                String[] spl = T.split(" ");
                int N = Integer.parseInt(spl[0]);
                int H = Integer.parseInt(spl[1]);

                int Num = N;int tlarge = 0;
                int hours = 0;int loss = 0;int z=0,y=0;
                boolean equal[] = new boolean[1003];

                while( Num > 0)
                {
                    String oper = in.readLine();
                    String[] op = oper.split(" ");
                    int v = Integer.parseInt(op[0]);
                    int t = Integer.parseInt(op[1]);
                    Arr[Num-1] = new Entry(v,t);
                    Num--;

                }
                while(y<N)
                {
                    loss += Arr[y].getV();
                    if(Arr[y].getT()>tlarge) tlarge=Arr[y].getT();
                    equal[Arr[y].getT()]=false;
                    y++;
                }
                QuickSort( 0, N-1);//from zero to no of tasks

                while(hours < H && z < N)
                {
                    if((equal[Arr[z].getT()]!=true) || hours<Arr[z].getT())  {
                        if(Arr[z].getT()<=tlarge) {
                            if(z<tlarge) {
                            loss -= Arr[z].getV();
                            equal[Arr[z].getT()]=true;
                            hours++;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    z++;
                }
                System.out.printf("%d\n",loss);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I suggest you explain what your logic is and why you think it's working. So we can give you clues where you may be thinking wrong

Comment: I have edited my code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What is wrong

1) Setting the array `equal` to `false` for the range `[0,N-1]`. But it actually is used for the range `[0,H]` and nothing says `H` should be smaller than `N`. This means there could be an impact cross testcase.

2)

```
if(z<tlarge)
```

Why should you only do the task when the index in the sorted array is smaller than `tlarge`?

```
4 2 
10 1
10 1
10 1
1 2

expected: 20
result: 21
```

3) You are not setting equal to true for the timeslot that you use for it.

```
if((equal[Arr[z].getT()]!=true) || hours<Arr[z].getT()) {
    if(Arr[z].getT()<=tlarge) {
        if(z<tlarge) {
            loss -= Arr[z].getV();
            equal[Arr[z].getT()]=true;
            hours++;
        }
    }
}
```

By this you can pass through even when the slot has already been taken.

```
4 4 
1 1
5 2
5 2
1 4

expected: 1
result: 0
```

These are probably only the main issues you should fix. But as you can see this algorithm needs some rethinking.

#### Suggested fix (spoiler)

- Handle all tasks sorted as you do, but set equal to true for the highest spot possible, lower than its end time.
- If no lower is found, the task can't be done and its value should be added to the loss

Full code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> {
        private final int v, t;

        Entry(int v, int t) {
            this.v = v;
            this.t = t;
        }

        public int getV() {
            return v;
        }

        public int getT() {
            return t;
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Entry oth) {
            if(this.v == oth.v){
                Integer.signum(this.t - oth.t);
            }
            return Integer.signum(oth.v - this.v);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            int N = in.nextInt();
            int H = in.nextInt();
            Entry[] arr = new Entry[N];

            for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
                int v = in.nextInt();
                int t = in.nextInt();
                arr[i] = new Entry(v, t);
            }
            Arrays.sort(arr);
            Entry[] entryByHour = new Entry[H+1];
            int loss = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                int j=arr[i].t-1;
                while(j>=0 && entryByHour[j] != null){
                    j--;
                }
                if(j < 0){
                    loss += arr[i].v;
                }else{
                    entryByHour[j] = arr[i];
                }
            }           
            System.out.printf("%d\n", loss);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

#### Extra

You may want to put your code **when it's fixed** on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as well. I've got the feeling you are used to program in c or c++. But in java you can do a lot of things more easily and surely cleaner. Like for sorting use [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) by using the [IComparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface on your `Entry`. And other best practices where you and others may benefit from.

Comment: for the second case - total time (4 1) cannot be less than any task's individual time.

Comment: for the first case I have made changes with setting equal flag to false for individual task hours.

Comment: Oops, I've added the wrong case. I'm wondering why you are checking z (which is the index in the sorted array) to be smaller than the maximum T.. Why would you do that?

Comment: for test case 1 (hours<H) wont work as individual max time is 2 hrs. so (20 1) is not considered as loss as the equal flag is false for it.

Comment: With your suggested fix I am not able to pass your test case. Please elaborate on your suggestion.

Comment: if the slot of getT in equal is taken, find the max spot that is smaller than getT that is still not taken. So loop from getT -> 1 and break if found, if not found it should be added to the total loss.

Comment: Amended my code with passing your test case but still it is failing with 100% WA. Have a look in above edited logic.

Comment: Since you have everything still wrong, there might be something wrong with the reading as well. If you want to be sure it works you can use `Scanner` instead, it is known to handle this very well although it's slower. But you want to get it all correct in the first place I guess. In case of troubles I added my example solution for you as well. Hope you can learn something from it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Got accepted with Scanner for reading input.